# CMake:: Specify Run Command for Target in IDE

Tags: cmake, doxygen, clion

Most IDEs allow you to click a button to run a target when developing code. I'm looking for a way to specify the functionality of that button from CMake.

This is particularly relevant because I'm generating Documentation from Doxygen, and I'd like to launch a browser with the documentation from within the IDE, based on the configuration of the CMakeLists.txt. For example, consider the following custom target :

```
set(doxyfile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile)
set(DOX_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/doc )
add_custom_target(Documentation
        COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${doxyfile}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${DOX_BINARY_DIR}
        COMMENT "Generating Documentation"
        )
```

Preferably I'm looking for something more elegant than a build step hack. I'm aware, for example, that one can specify a custom target to launch a browser .

```
add_custom_target(Open_Documentation
        COMMAND google-chrome ${DOX_BINARY_DIR}/html/index.html
        )
```

Ideally, I'd be looking for a command that allows me to specify the run-executable for a given target:

```
set_execute_command(TARGET Documentation 
        COMMAND google-chrome ${DOX_BINARY_DIR}/html/index.html
        )
```

Does any one know of a way that this can be achieved?

Comment: I think cmake is not the main 'trouble' here. Your question is CLion specific.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak I've had the same problem with Visual Studio in the past - I always land up hacking custom build targets to do the stuff that I want. Besides which, this would ideally be settable from within cmake. I figure it must be doable - I'm assuming that there must be a target property that allows you specify the output executable (which I'm guessing the IDE would pick up as something it can execute)

Comment: most IDEs I've seen simply run executable generated during compilation. Here you have different situation which may require different aproaches for each IDE. How about making a `target` which would be a simple exe starting browser with desired url?

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm doing at the moment, but I'd like to avoid adding another target when it would be far more intuitive to run a current target. I feel that this should be within CMake's scope of interest, and would be useful for developing concurrently with CMake and CLion/VS/CodeBlocks etc. I'm guessing this is probably doable but I just don't know how.

Comment: frankly speaking I do not agree with You. I think that's not what cmake should care about. Some IDEs offer starting custom exe as startup project (Visual Studio or KDevelop for example). I'm not sure about CLion as I've never used it.

Comment: I suppose, although the point is moot. This is a frequently recurring problem that I, and I'm sure others, have. You're not able to launch an external program or command directly from the IDE, and are forced to implement a separate build target to accommodate such functionality. This typically occur when using building documentation or other extraneous tasks.
While I'm sure this falls under the "nice to have" category, such functionality should be possible within the CMake framework. Whether it belongs there or not is part of another discussion, my interest lies in whether this is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake add_custom_target(): Run custom command using 'Debug->Start Debugging'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475532/cmake-add-custom-target-run-custom-command-using-debug-start-debugging)