# How to create an artificial circular dependency between targets

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake, dependencies, circular-dependency

I have an executable (game engine) which exports symbols (I've used `set_target_properties(game PROPERTIES ENABLE_EXPORTS ON)`).

I have a bunch of plugins that link to that executable:

```
foreach(plugin ${PLUGINS})
    target_link_libraries(${plugin} game)
endforeach()
```

They are loaded dynamically with `LoadLibrary`/`dlopen` by the executable.

When I press F5 in Visual Studio and I start the game I don't get the changed plugins rebuilt because the game does not depend on them - it's the other way around.

I wanted to do the following:

```
foreach(plugin ${PLUGINS})
    add_dependencies(game ${plugin})
endforeach()
```

but it introduces a circular dependency between each plugin and the game. How can I solve my F5 problem?

Comment: How do you use the exported functions in your plug-in code? If you have the interface descriptions hard-coded or you have it in an header file, then there is only an indirect dependency from `plugin` to `game`. So what happens if you only use your "`game` depends on `plugin`"  variant? Should work fine from my perspective.

Comment: @Florian well I call into the engine... almost every piece of functionality is exported from the executable. I use the engine headers in the plugins... The "```plugin``` depends on ```game```" dependency is here to stay. I'm wondering how to make the F5 workflow work as well...

Comment: If I access from the plugins everything the engine exports by using ```getProcAddress``` instead of ```__declspec(dllimport)``` annotated forward declarations I could remove the "```plugin``` depends on ```game```" dependency, but that wouldn't be practical to code...

Comment: I didn't fully follow/understand that, but I think I found a solution - I can set the ```ALL_BUILD``` (created by CMake) to be the startup project (for F5) and just setup it's command to run the executable

Comment: Ok, I forgot that under Windows you need to generate the import libraries first, meaning you need to build `game` before the plug-ins (because the import libraries are linked statically). So I've run some tests with your scenario and Visual Studio and will put the results in an answer.

Comment: Is it an option to split the game exe into two targets? One library that contains all code that can be linked into the plugin and into the executable and one executable that only contains main.cpp. When you do that, you can use the ````add_dependencies()```` trick with your executable. It works in our project here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a "chicken-and-egg" problem since the `game` build will generate the import libraries needed by `plugin`. So you can't build `plugin` before `game`.

I've given your scenario a try and

1. If I force a rebuild in a `POST_BUILD` step, I get obviously a recursive build call:

   ```perl
   add_custom_command(
       TARGET game 
       POST_BUILD 
           COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --target ALL_BUILD --config $<CONFIG>
   )
   ```
2. If I construct a separate target as a "runner" target, I would probably confusing others using my project:

   ```perl
   file(WRITE nobuild.cpp "")
   add_executable(game_runner nobuild.cpp)

   set_source_files_properties(nobuild.cpp PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY 1)
   set_target_properties(game_runner PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "game")

   foreach(plugin ${PLUGINS})
       add_dependencies(game_runner ${plugin})
   endforeach()
   ```
3. So probably your suggestion of re-using the `ALL_BUILD` target is the best one. And for auto-generating your required `.user` settings you may find the following interesting:

   [CMake add_custom_target(): Run custom command using 'Debug->Start Debugging'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475532/cmake-add-custom-target-run-custom-command-using-debug-start-debugging)

---

I've used the following to test your scenario:

```perl
project(TestPlugins)

file(WRITE main.cpp "int main() { return 0; }")
file(WRITE empty.cpp "")

add_executable(game main.cpp)
set_target_properties(game PROPERTIES ENABLE_EXPORTS ON)
set_target_properties(game PROPERTIES WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

add_executable(plugin1 empty.cpp)
add_executable(plugin2 empty.cpp)

set(PLUGINS plugin1 plugin2)
foreach(plugin ${PLUGINS})
    target_link_libraries(${plugin} game)
endforeach()
```

Comment: thanks! your other answer that generates the .user file also is good and it worked! no more manual setup :)
you're one of the most active about cmake in stack overflow - thank you sir.